# Does pytorch broadcast consume less memory than expand?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, array-broadcasting

Does pytorch operations using broadcast consume less memory than expand? For example, are the following two programs different in memory usage?

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(20,1)
y = torch.randn(1,20)
z = x*y
```

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(20,1).expand(-1,20)
y = torch.randn(1,20).expand(20,-1)
z = x*y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation page of [`torch.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand):

> Expanding a tensor does not allocate new memory, but only creates a new view on the existing tensor

You can experiment it yourself by profiling the calls (here in Colab):

```
>>> x = torch.randn(200,1)
>>> y = torch.randn(1,200)
>>> %memit z = x*y
peak memory: 286.85 MiB, increment: 0.31 MiB

>>> x = torch.randn(200,1).expand(-1,200)
>>> y = torch.randn(1,200).expand(200,-1)
>>> %memit z = x*y
peak memory: 286.86 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
```

---

`%memit` is a magic function provided by [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/):

```
pip install memory_profiler

%load_ext memory_profiler
```